# How do you determine a reasonable minimum window of time between actions as to prevent flooding?

Tags: response-time, moderation

I'm planning some code that will prevent flooding for a project I'm working on. I'm wondering, how do you determine what interval of time is necessary to wait in between actions?

I've seen this anywhere from a few seconds, to a few minutes, to daily limits depending on the application.Thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

What you need to do is run some test cases. What could a user possible do, how much and how fast. Then once you know which use cases would use the most actions you know your limit is there and you can add a small bit of padding on top so a regular user wouldn't run into it.

Answer (score 0):

These types of questions are completely dependent by the users. In which case, testing is required.

However, my company did something similar. We have an alert window that warns the users they are about to be timed out after 1 hour of use. The alert window also allows the users 10mins to extend their time for another hour, otherwise they will be logged out by default.

This will not only give a chance for users who are using the application more time, but it'll also time out those who may have the app open for too long.